# how to use ARGV in a method in a ruby

Tags: ruby, argv

Can someone please give me a simple example of using ARGV in a method in ruby, i just need to understand it better, i have tried using

```
def greet(ARGV)
  puts "Hello #{ARGV}"
end
```

Comment: What are the command line arguments that you want to pass to your script and what's the expected output?

Comment: Identifiers starting with upper case letter are "constants" (in the somewhat unusual idea of what Ruby sees as constant), and therefore can't be used for a local variable or as a formal parameter. If you name your parameter `aRGV`, it will work.

Comment: Aside from this, it is not wise to provide your own definition of the constant `ARGV`, because this (like, for instance, STDOUT) is already set by the Ruby runtime, when your program is started.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Don't use constants to collect method arguments, especially special constants like *ARGV*. Use positional or collected-positional arguments instead.

### Using *ARGV* Generally Implies Command-Line Arguments

[*ARGV* is a predefined global constant in Ruby.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants) You can think of it as an Array of String values that contain the arguments passed to the Ruby interpreter, but while you technical *can* redefine it at runtime you should not be doing that in most cases, and certainly not redefining a global constant as part of a method definition.

*ARGV* works like an Array of arguments passed to the interpreter like Bash's positional arguments of `$1` to `$9` except zero-based, e.g. `ARGV[0]` is the first positional argument. You can also get at *ARGV* through [ARGF#argv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/ARGF.html), but that's not your use case here.

### Passing Positional Arguments to a Method

If you want to pass a *single* argument to a method, just give it a non-constant name. For example:

```rb
def greet(name)
  puts "Hello, #{name}!"
end
```

If you really want to pass a variable number of arguments to a method as a named Array, then you can do that, too. For example:

```rb
def greet(*names)
  names.each { |name| puts "Hello, #{name}!" }
end

%w[Alice Bob Carol].map { |name| greet(name) }
```

In this case, you're collecting a list of names the method-local Array *names*, and then iterating over the items in that Array. There are some edge cases with this that are outside the scope of your original question such as empty arrays, nil values, and passing Array objects as positional arguments, but again those edge cases are outside the scope of your original question.

### Summary

Use *ARGV* if you're passing arguments on the command line. Otherwise, use positional arguments or collected-Array arguments in your method definitions.

Comment: @Gaelan Thanks for pointing out the error. It's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def greet(name)
  "Hello #{name}"
end

puts greet(ARGV[0])
```

when you run in the terminal you enter **file_name.rb user**# then you enter your argument before running the file and you will get something like *Hello user*

Comment: Just to elaborate on this answer - `ARGV` is an array, so if your ruby script is invoked with multiple arguments, then you can access them by using the appropriate array index: `ruby file.rb one two three` means ARGV is `["one", "two", three"]`